# C++ code blurts out two very different outputs while trying to print the same array of strings twice in a row

Tags: c++, arrays, string, cout, pacman

I am trying to make a simple console pacman game and I'm experiencing this obscure print output coming from the following source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){
    std::ifstream map_file;
    int map_width, map_height;
    try{
        map_file.open("map.txt");
    }
    catch(int e){
        std::cout << "An exception occured." << std::endl;
    }
    map_file >> map_width;
    map_file >> map_height;
    char* map[map_height];
    for(int i = 0; i < map_height; i++){
        std::string temp_line;
        getline(map_file, temp_line);
        map[i] = (char*)temp_line.c_str();
        std::cout << map[i] << std::endl;

    }
    system("pause");
    for(int i = 0; i < map_height; i++){
        std::cout << map[i] << std::endl;

    }
    return 0;   
}
```

I will copy the two runs of calling std::cout from that code here again and attach a screenshot of what was output in the console:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < map_height; i++){
        std::string temp_line;
        getline(map_file, temp_line);
        map[i] = (char*)temp_line.c_str();
        std::cout << map[i] << std::endl;

    }
```

Other printing run:

```
    system("pause");
    for(int i = 0; i < map_height; i++){
        std::cout << map[i] << std::endl;

    }
```

Here comes the screenshot: block of text before the system("pause") is the content of the input map.txt file and is displayed exactly how it is written in map.txt, but the second printing run is totally unexpected.

[image: obscure printout screenshot]

My question is simply what could be causing this.

EDIT: I realized

```
map[i] = (char*)temp_line.c_str();
```

performs a shallow, and not a deep copy, thus I fixed the issue by instead dynamically allocating a

```
char[map_width + 1]
```

at

```
map[i]
```

and performing

```
strcpy(map[i], temp_line.c_str());
```

I am still interested as how could have the original program possibly written

```
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
ystem32\cmd.exe
```

Comment: For your edit, make sure you are saving enough space for the null terminator as well (ie. temp.length() + 1 space). If that doesn't work, provide your most up-to-date code.

Comment: For future reference, using paddy's suggestion is better as the question is tagged with C++, and using those methods would help you handle these problems easier.

Comment: Once your code wanders into undefined behaviour Crom only knows what the results will be. Maybe you'll get extra crap on the command line. Maybe your PC will gain sentience, seize control of the world's nuclear arsenals, and exterminate mankind. I'd prefer the first to the latter, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Undefined behaviour.  You are storing pointers that are no longer valid:

```
map[i] = (char*)temp_line.c_str();
```

If your `map` stored `std::string` values instead of pointers, it would be fine to do this:

```
map[i] = temp_line;
```

I also notice you're using variable-length arrays.  Don't.  Use a `std::vector` instead.  The easiest way for a beginner would be to do it like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> map( map_height );
for( int i = 0; i < map_height; i++ )
{
    getline( map_file, map[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because your string `temp` is going out of scope and with it, the pointer (`c_str`) associated with it goes as well. So your `map[i]` points to garbage data. You need to deep copy contents with something like `strcpy`. See [strcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) for how you can use strcpy for this. (Hint, you need to actually allocate memory for the source string as well as the null terminator)

That's also UB (Undefined Behavior). (Trying to print the pointers after the loss, that is)

Comment: `strcpy` does _not_ deep copy the contents.

Comment: @paddy if you're talking about "by itself", well, it comes with the contract that you provide sufficient space in your destination string. So, I guess in that sense it wouldn't, but I'd still say that it allows you to deep copy.

Comment: If you use the term "deep copy" in reference to strings, you imply that the necessary memory allocations are also done.  You have recommended replacing UB in the form of illegal _reads_ with UB that instead performs illegal _writes_.

Comment: Not necessarily illegal writes. I assumed the OP would check what strcpy does and how it's used, if they didn't know. In any case, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < map_height; i++){
    std::string temp_line;
    getline(map_file, temp_line);
    map[i] = (char*)temp_line.c_str();
    std::cout << map[i] << std::endl;

}
```

You are storing the internal c string of the temp_line variable, but the temp_line variable is destroyed after each iteration of the above loop.  So basically, your array of char* variables are pointing to random garbage.

```
std::string map[map_height];
for(int i = 0; i < map_height; i++){
    getline(map_file, map[i]);
    std::cout << map[i] << std::endl;

}
system("pause");
for(int i = 0; i < map_height; i++){
    std::cout << map[i] << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you probably suspect, the "random garbage" that you're seeing isn't really random.  Yes, it's the consequence of undefined behaviour and you shouldn't really consider it, but why those specific sequence of characters?

I suspect that this happens to be the contents of `argv[0]`.  When the OS calls an application, it calls `main` and gives two parameters: `argc` (number of arguments) and `argv` (array containing command-line arguments).  `argv[0]` is the name of your application. C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe is the command-prompt and is often the parent process of an application, so I could imagine that the OS wrote that string into the first few pieces of memory of the application.

Because your code uses the `int main()` definition instead of the `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` definition, your code isn't designed to access that block of memory, but (not so) random access pointed one of your strings to that location of memory which is on the stack and early in the program's memory register.